# How to pin multiple SKNodes on one ARAnchor?

Tags: ios, arkit, sknode, aranchor

I came across an obstacle during my ARkit project that use ARSKView.

I want to achive when use tap on the screen and an ARAnchor is created, multiple SKNodes will pop up from the same anchor. Since I will need to interact with each of the node individually,

By default I see that form the func view there is only one output of SKnode.

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode?
```

I am very new to ARKit, and even Swift 4 so I would like your guidence.  Please let me know if there is anything else that I need to clarify.

Thank you

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do, what have you tried (show some code), and what problem did you encounter. These details need to be in the **body** of the question.

Comment: Hi jdv, I am new of being an contributor here at stackoverflow. And thank you for your reminder. I have solved my problem. As rickster suggested, I am able to achieve what I wanted by adding new child node to the parent node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From pretty early in [the `SKNode` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode):

> Nodes are organized hierarchically into node trees, similar to how views and subviews work

Anywhere in SpriteKit (as used together with ARKit or otherwise) where you can use one `SKNode` (or node subclass), you can use multiple nodes by adding them as children of one node. See "Creating the Node Tree" in the aforelinked doc, the [`addChild(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483054-addchild) method, etc.

Comment: Hi rickster, thank you for your quick reply! I figured this out as well by adding new nodes to the parent node.